# pygobject-2.28.6 won't configure: No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found, how do I resolve?

Tags: cygwin, pygobject, pkg-config, gobject, gobject-introspection

I'm trying to get pygobject-2.28.6 to compile in cygwin (version in repository is 2.28.4 which has some issues). Here is the tail of ./configure:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.24.0... yes (version 2.34.3)
checking for ffi... checking for FFI... yes
checking for GIO... yes
checking for GIOUNIX... yes
checking for GI... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.24.0
        gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 0.10.2
    ) were not met:

No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GI_CFLAGS
and GI_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have gobject-introspection 1.34.2-3 installed. As seen here:

```
$ whereis gobject-introspection
gobject-introspection: /lib/gobject-introspection /usr/lib/gobject-introspection
```

and here

```
$ whereis gobject-introspection-1.0
gobject-introspection-1: /usr/share/gobject-introspection-1.0
```

I've tried setting GI_CFLAGS and GI_LIBS in configure = to /lib/ and /usr/lib/ (and even /usr/share/) but to no avail. What else can I do to try and resolve this? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You're probably missing the development package.  The package name varies by distribution, but it's the one containing `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gobject-introspection-1.0.pc` (or `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/gobject-introspection-1.0.pc` for some 64-bit distros):

- Fedora, CentOS, RHEL, *etc.*: **gobject-introspection-devel**
- Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, *etc.*: **libgirepository1.0-dev**
- Arch: **gobject-introspection**
- FreeBSD: **gobject-introspection**
- Cygwin: **libgirepository1.0-devel**
- msys2: **mingw-w64-x86_64-gobject-introspection** and/or **mingw-w64-i686-gobject-introspection**

Comment: I can't find any such package available. I've given up and decided not to use cygwin for the purpose I had intended. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Stupac Good choice. Cygwin is pretty terrible. I know your comment is old, but nowadays I've had much more success using WSL than I ever hoped for using cygwin.

Answer (score 21):

I got this to compile on cygwin. The package you need is: `libgirepository1.0-devel`.

In Ubuntu it's called `libgirepository1.0-dev`

Answer (score 4):

For macOS {mine is(intel cpu)}:

```
 brew install pygobject3 gtk+3
 pip install --no-use-pep517 PyGObject
```

It worked in the python 2.7 virtual environment.

Comment: For my M1 it was sufficient just to run`brew install pygobject3` and then just pip install without the flags

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so this is really meant to be an addendum to nemequ's answer:

- MSYS2: **mingw-w64-x86_64-gobject-introspection** and/or **mingw-w64-i686-gobject-introspection**

Answer (score 0):

My error message while running `pip install pygobject`:

```
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.2.tar.gz (719 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pycairo>=1.16.0
  Using cached pycairo-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pygobject
  Building wheel for pygobject (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pygobject (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pygtkcompat
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/repository
      copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/repository
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gi/overrides
      running build_ext
      Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'gobject-introspection-1.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.56.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygobject
Failed to build pygobject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pygobject, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

did not mention 'gobject-introspection-1.0' but this [doc](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html?highlight=wheels#arch-dep) mentions commands setting `gobject-introspection` and resolved my problem smoothly.

```
sudo pacman -S --noconfirm python-wheel
sudo pacman -S --noconfirm base-devel openssl zlib git gobject-introspection
```