# Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path in ubuntu

Tags: python, flask, pygobject

this is the error i am getting while uploading my project to heroku.

```
remote:            running build_ext
remote:            Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc'
remote:            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:            No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found
remote:            Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
remote:            
remote:            Try installing it with: 'sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev'
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tqn048tg/PyGObject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6agyazal-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tqn048tg/PyGObject/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

i am already installed libgirepository1.0.
packages in requirements.txt are succesfully installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygobject-2.28.6 won't configure: No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found, how do I resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025730/pygobject-2-28-6-wont-configure-no-package-gobject-introspection-1-0-found)

Answer (score 14):

First I'd try to install the developer package of `libgirepository1.0`. That's Linux distribution dependent how you'd achieve that and what is the exact name of the developer package:

- Fedora, CentOS, RHEL, *etc.*: **gobject-introspection-devel**
- Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, *etc.*: **libgirepository1.0-dev**
- Arch: **gobject-introspection**

If that doesn't help then you may be missing some packages from your `requirements.txt`, as an example see: [No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found while deploying to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362778/no-package-gobject-introspection-1-0-found-while-deploying-to-heroku)

To know what you are missing we'd need to know more about your configuration.