# Unable to install gobject-introspection - symbol lookup error: and undefined symbol: g_unicode_type_get_type

Tags: linux, gobject-introspection

Unable to install gobject-introspection -  symbol lookup error: and undefined symbol: g_unicode_type_get_type

I tried to compile Gtk4, and download gobject-introspection 1.30, 1.40, 1.50, 1.64.1. All failed with the same exact error except the last one that produced another error.

Errors for gobject-introspection 1.30, 1.40, 1.50,

```
 CCLD     _giscanner.la
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       g_ir_compiler-compiler.o
  CCLD     g-ir-compiler
  CC       g_ir_generate-generate.o
  CCLD     g-ir-generate
  CC       g_ir_inspect-g-ir-inspect.o
  CCLD     g-ir-inspect
  CC       gi_dump_types-gdump.o
  CC       gi_dump_types-gi-dump-types.o
  CCLD     gi-dump-types
  CC       glib_print-glib-print.o
  CCLD     glib-print
  GEN      g-ir-scanner
  GEN      g-ir-annotation-tool
  GEN      g-ir-doc-tool
  GISCAN   GLib-2.0.gir
g-ir-scanner: GLib: warning: 736 warnings suppressed (use --warn-all to see them)
  GISCAN   GObject-2.0.gir
/home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0/tmp-introspectCppLzz/GObject-2.0: symbol lookup error: /home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0/tmp-introspectCppLzz/GObject-2.0: undefined symbol: g_unicode_type_get_type
Command '[u'/home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0/tmp-introspectCppLzz/GObject-2.0', u'--introspect-dump=/home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0/tmp-introspectCppLzz/functions.txt,/home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0/tmp-introspectCppLzz/dump.xml']' returned non-zero exit status 127
Makefile:3520: recipe for target 'GObject-2.0.gir' failed
make[2]: *** [GObject-2.0.gir] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0'
Makefile:2810: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/elias/Downloads/gobject-introspection-1.50.0'
Makefile:1570: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem finding the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025730/pygobject-2-28-6-wont-configure-no-package-gobject-introspection-1-0-found/18027346#18027346):

> You're probably missing the development package. The package name
> varies by distribution, but it's the one containing
> /usr/lib/pkgconfig/gobject-introspection-1.0.pc (or
> /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/gobject-introspection-1.0.pc for some 64-bit
> distros):
>
> Fedora, CentOS, RHEL, etc.: gobject-introspection-devel
>
> Debian,Ubuntu, Mint, etc.: libgirepository1.0-dev Arch: gobject-introspection
>
> FreeBSD: gobject-introspection
>
> Cygwin: libgirepository1.0-devel msys2:
>
> mingw-w64-x86_64-gobject-introspection and/or mingw-w64-i686-gobject-introspection